# can't print the array or assign to it

Tags: c++, string

the code below is supposed to take an input from the user `char s1[] = "[1 -2.5 3;4 5.25 6;7 8 9.12]";`
and take only the numbers in it then cast them to be floats and put them in an array
but when i try and cout the array it prints nothing just the numbers

```cpp
char s1[] = "[1 -2.5 3;4 5.25 6;7 8 9.12]";
char s2 [100] ;
float matrix [2][2];
char* cutter(char s[])
{

    char delim[] = " ;][";
    char *token = strtok(s,delim);
    while (token)
    {
        cout << token << endl;

        token = strtok(NULL,delim);

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j< 2;j++){
                matrix [i][j]=strtof(token, NULL);
            }
        }

    }

return token;
}

void showmatrix(float m[2][2]){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
                cout << m[i][j];
            }
        }
}

int main(){
    cutter(s1);
    showmatrix(matrix);
    //cin.getline(s2,100);
    //cutter(s2);

}
```

Comment: Your show matrix has a `float` return type yet returns nothing? Also your loop condition is wrong, it should be < 2, you're reading out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Your code runs a UB `for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){` make it `< 2`. Also a function that fails to provide a valid return statement is an erroneous.

Comment: And you only have enough room for two values per array dimension, but you're trying to add 3. Undefined behavior abounds.

Comment: i did fix some of what i could understand

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not run on my machine. You should change your loop condition as the others have suggested, and move the placement of the `token = strtok(NULL,delim);` code within your `cutter` function.

This code runs:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char s1[] = "[1 -2.5 3;4 5.25 6;7 8 9.12]";
//char s2 [100] ;
float matrix [2][2];

char* cutter(char s[])
{
    char delim[] = " ;][";
    char *token = strtok(s,delim);
    while (token)
    {
        cout << token << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = strtof(token, NULL);
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
    return token;
}

void showmatrix(float m[2][2]){
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j< 2;j++){
            cout << m[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    cutter(s1);
    showmatrix(matrix);
    //cin.getline(s2,100);
    //cutter(s2);
}
```

Also, please try to post complete examples of your code, including any `using` declarations and included headers.